# URL redirect in Azure Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

We have migrated documents from one application to another. Destination path is different by document names are same. These documents are referred in many other applications and documents that are difficult to find and update.
Can I use front door service to create a mapping list of url redirection?

For example below if one of a site.

I can create URL redirect url and set destination host and path, but how to fill in document name dynamically in rule?

Source:
https://source.com/Project-ABC/Documents/<document-name.docx/ppt/xlsx>

Destination:
https://destination.com/DocumentCenter/Project-ABC/<document-name.docx/ppt/xlsx>

I can create URL redirect url and set destination host and path, but how to fill in document name dynamically in rule?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the file in the applications is stored in folders and the URL of the respective files is hard to get with the respective path, but the URL can be redirected to any existing path (i.e. azure/home to azure/privacy).

Yes, we can use Azure Front Door to create a mapping list of URL redirection. we can use the URL `Rewrite` action to rewrite the URL path and query string. we can use the regular expression pattern to capture the substring for later use in composing the expression for rewriting the URL path. we can also use the Set action to set the new value of the path and query string.

> Reference MSDoc for  Front Door ,  @Sampath and for uploading the files into [web application](https://github.com/corespider/file-upload-in-aspnetcore-mvc).

- I created a sample web application for uploading the file into a web application and deployed it into the Azure app service and the file in the respective application can be found in Kudu tools.

  [image]
- Connected the Azure app service with Front Door from above stack, set the rules from doc and stack.
- I was able to route from Privacy to the default page for the custom endpoint Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/how-to-configure-endpoints)

**Output:**

[image]